# Do old iOS versions have an equivalent of WOW64 for running 32 bit apps?

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit

Given that iOS 11 dropped compatibility for 32-bit applications, I am wondering how these were previously supported.  Was there a compatibility layer similar to WOW64 on Windows?  If so, what is the rationale for getting rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All prior versions of iOS could be installed on at least one 32-bit device. So there were up-to-date 32-bit versions of the iOS libraries. So launching a 32-bit application just means telling the CPU to run 32-bit code and providing those copies of the system libraries.

Note that one of those steps is having the CPU run 32-bit code.

Apple designs its own CPUs, and designs them explicitly for their iOS devices. So the safest speculation is that Apple no longer wishes to include 32-bit execution on its CPUs, and doesn't see sufficient value in a Rosetta-esque CPU emulation library.